# Wording on reputation page doesn't appear to match behavior

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On the individual user reputation page, i.e. `site/reputation`, there is a line which reads:

> earned at least 200 reputation on __ days

However, running the total manually it appears that the count is actually the number of days in which the net gain was 200 or greater.

For example, a day in which I earned 200 reputation but also gave a +50 bounty is apparently not counted.

I recommend updating the wording to read: **net gain of at least 200 reputation** ...

Comment: The `/reputation` page is no longer maintained. We've known that information is inaccurate for a long time.

Comment: @animuson Would you provide a reference for that?

Comment: @animuson or anyone else: is the non-maintenance stated policy?

Comment: @MrWizard: They never officially stated "we are no longer maintaining it" - but when they made the massive overhaul on the reputation history which allowed users to track deletion events, etc without the need for that page, it became obsolete. I highly recommend not using it for reputation recalcs (they stated the button would likely be removed altogether when they originally posted about the overhauls), as it can sometimes not match what should actually happen. As well, that page does not include deleted posts at all, so none of the statistics will include them either.